# Are the 3 resistors in parallel or in series?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance

Are \$R_1\$, \$R_3\$, and \$R_2\$ in series? or are \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ in parallel?  I'm new to all this.  Here's the circuit:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resistors in parallel but with a capacitor in between them?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/412507/resistors-in-parallel-but-with-a-capacitor-in-between-them)

Comment: Check the answer of mine.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/502659/how-to-combine-two-resistors-with-a-voltage-source/502706#502706

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, \$\text{R}_3\$, \$\text{R}_4\$, \$\text{R}_5\$ and \$\text{R}_6\$ are in parallel and they are in series with \$\text{R}_1\$ and \$\text{R}_2\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSnfhq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the total resistance is:

$$\text{R}_\text{total}=\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{1}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{1}{\text{R}_5}+\frac{1}{\text{R}_6}}$$

Comment: so i get the equivalent resistance of R3 R4 R5 and R6, then i add it to r1 and r2, so r1 and r2 are in series ?

Comment: @AhmadBenos See my edit

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AhmadBenos You're welcome, I'm glad that I could be of any help.

Answer (score 5):

Just for a definitional answer:

- Two resistors are **in parallel** if each terminal of resistor A is connected to the terminals of resistor B
- Two resistors are **in series** if only one terminal of resistor A is connected to a terminal of resistor B (and their common point isn't connected to anything else).

Just because it's worth saying: it doesn't matter how you **draw them**, it **only matters how you connect them**.

As for solving these kinds of problems, you can always replace two parallel resistors with another resistor of value 1/( 1/Ra + 1/Rb ), regardless of what other connection there might be.  (Series resistors, on the other hand, can only be replaced by a single resistor if nothing else is connected to their common point.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy178Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I want to deny the fact that the 3rd figure of parallel figures is not series but parallel..

Comment: The definition of series is not correct. Elements are in series if just one terminal of each element is connected to together **and nothing else is connected at that point**. I know that you say that this is a condition for resistors to be combined, but it is actually a condition for them to be **in series**.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson thanks for your comment.  How would you describe the two resistors of a potential divider across say power and ground?  We add their resistances to calculate the load they present to the power supply, because they are in series.  Even when we connect (say) the base of some transistor there, those resistors are still in parallel.  How would you describe them?

Comment: @muyustan thanks for your comment, but I'm not sure what you're saying.  Are you saying R3a and R3b are not in parallel?

Comment: Oh no, your figure is correct. They are in parallel. It is just that, they look like they are in series intuitively

Comment: As long as you have just the two resistors forming the divider then they are in series. The important aspect is that the current through them **must** be exactly the same...the voltage divider equation depends on that. When you connect something else at the point where the two resistors connect then the two resistors are no longer in series...the current through them **may be different**. It is absolutely vital that we keep this in mind. You could say that "as long as the base current is **much much smaller** than the divider current, then the two resistors still work like a voltage divider".

Comment: But this site is littered with questions from beginners who want to use a resistive voltage divider to charge their phone from a 12V supply. Over and over again we have to correct the misconception that you still have a valid voltage divider regardless of what you connect between the resistors.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson ... excellent points, amended my answer

Comment: @muyustan ... this is in fact the exact reason I added example R3

Comment: @all: the resistors shown as an example for parallel connection actually meet the requirements for series and parallel at the same time. Adding a third resistor is required to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Resistors R3, R4, R5 and R6 are connected in parallel. And this circuit is connected in series to R1 and R2.

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually R3,R4,R5,R6 are in parallel combination as the voltage across the resistors is same and the combination and R1,R2 are in series as the current will be same through them

Comment: Isn't this exactly what all of the answers said?