# The meaning of leads in equivalent resistances

Tags: circuit-analysis

Following on this question ([How to combine two resistors with a voltage source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/502659/how-to-combine-two-resistors-with-a-voltage-source)) and faced with a similar example, it would seem the opposite applies. I am given the circuit below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDZ0YP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and told Rth is `(R1||R2)+(R3||R4)`. In this question ([How to combine two resistors with a voltage source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/502659/how-to-combine-two-resistors-with-a-voltage-source)), it seemed the terminals were implied to be meaningless, implying that here, `R1––R2` and `R3––R4`. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

In response to some of the answers below, I will redraw the circuit to better illustrate my confusion:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGatAS.png)</sup>

What is the role of the red leads? What is the meaning of asking for a resistance between these vs "the whole circuit"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just take away the red nodes as you did. You want to find the equivalent resistance as seen at these two nodes, so if the nodes are removed then you can't get a meaningful solution anymore. In problems like this we assume that something will eventually be connected at the red nodes.

And, when you combine circuit elements in series the node that previously existed between them is no longer part of the circuit....it is buried somewhere inside the single new element that is equivalent to the two original elements.

Comment: Thank you! Here the role of leads or nodes is finally clarified: you cannot ask for a resistance without them. In other words, asking for the resistance of "the whole circuit" is meaningless without specifying from which terminals. That was what I was missing in this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/502659/how-to-combine-two-resistors-with-a-voltage-source.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate your Thevenin resistance, you need to kill the voltage source. You do that by shorting it out. See if that makes the circuit look more understandable.

**EDIT**:  Showing redrawn circuit.

[image]

Comment: I did! How does it make R1 and R2 or R3 and R4 any more parallel to each other?

Comment: Take your time and redraw the circuit.  See my edit above. Keep simplifying until you find the equivalent resistance between the red terminals (Rth).

Comment: Is it not the case that I can consider the red terminals as not being there, since they are open (i.e. not connected to anything), and therefore can combine R1 and R2 in series (similarly for R3 and R4)? Is the resistance between the red terminals not equivalent to asking for the resistance of the entire circuit?

Comment: Thank you for forcing me to clarify my question.