# How to obtain a Norton current (I_N) with resistors in the way

Tags: circuit-analysis

How is the Norton current I_N (over the red terminals) obtained in a circuit where the introduced short cannot return to a given current source I without going through some resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2AUxF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**EDIT**

The hate is strong for this question. If your concern is similar, then with a bit of time and bravery, you should find this post useful.

Comment: R3 and R4 are shorted out. Is this intended?

Comment: @Hearth Yes, but bear in mind the designated terminals (red) over which will I_N flow.

Comment: It seems you're making the same mistake as in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/503358/the-meaning-of-leads-in-equivalent-resistances, regarding the red segments. What they are meant for ?

Comment: @barrow I don't see it as the same issue. I would curious to know why you think it is.

Comment: In fact, certainly they are not the same, but the point is that it was not clear  what the red lines represent.for you. Anyway, from your last post below it seems that you (perhaps) understood the point to be more clear in your questions.

Comment: @barrow Since you could tell the questions were not the same, (perhaps) this one was sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5gnNR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The approach is to take into account the resistance faced along way from I, through the short I_N and back to I. Due to current division, $$I_N = {\frac{R_1||R_2}{R_{T}}}I$$ where $$R_{T} = R_1||R_2 + R_3||R_4$$

Comment: Are you sure about your calculations?  You know that the current division is related to elements in parallel, so my question is, what are, in your opinion, the elements in parallel for deriving the formula?

Comment: @barrow I'm sorry, what isn't clear?

Comment: It seems that your last drawing has nothing to do with the one on your first post; they are not comparable. In fact, the red line is a short, so in this way R1, R2, R3 and R4 are all in parallel with the current generator. In this case, it is a no sense asking about the current I_N...

Comment: @barrow Not sure why you are confused. The question drawing and this one are identical but for the explicit closure of the Norton short, as exemplified above with glen's answer (i.e. connecting glen's Node A and B together), creating I_N. The problem is solved in this way to make explicit the flow paths. And what you mentioned about all the resistors being parallel to I is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but your original question was very confusing, and in fact you have re-stated it differently about 2 hours ago, finally with the statement "the Norton current I_N", which was completely absent originally.  I'm not confused at all. The point here is that you proposed the original question in a very, very confusing way.

Comment: @barrow Glad you got it!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it helps to re-draw a circuit, in a way that helps to simplify analysis. The original (left) is equivalent to (right):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhgaJI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>